# СПП или однородные члены?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, спп, однородные-члены, союзные-слова

**Я вспоминаю времена, когда учился в школе**.

Это как пример, тут вроде **я вспоминаю** и **я учился**. Это СПП или тут однородные члены? Если СПП, то где тут сложность предложения, когда сказуемые относятся к одному подлежащему?

Answer (score 2):

***Я вспоминаю времена*** (какие?)***, когда учился в школе.***

Это сложноподчинённое предложение (СПП) с придаточным определительным, являющимся неполным (пропущено подлежащее, чтобы не было повтора). Сказуемые в обеих частях относятся к одному и тому же субъекту, но не могут считаться однородными.

> Однородные члены соединяются сочинительными союзами или просто перечислительной интонацией.
> Однородные члены могут иметь одинаковое или разное морфологическое выражение. [[Грамота.ру]](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/author/litnevskaya/part5#34101)

Например:
*Я **нашёл** интересную книгу и **буду читать** её весь день.

Я **нашёл** интересную книгу, **порадовался**, но **читать начну** завтра.

Я **вспоминаю** времена, когда учился в школе, и **радуюсь**.*

В нашем же случае имеется союзное слово "[**когда**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0&all=x)", относящееся к существительному "времена".

> Придаточные определительные отвечают на вопрос *какой?,* относятся к одному слову в главной части — существительному, местоимению или слову другой части речи в функции существительного — и располагаются после этого определяемого слова.
>
> Придаточные определительные присоединяются при помощи **союзных слов** — относительных местоимений *какой, который, чей, что* и местоименных наречий *где, куда, откуда, когда.* [[Грамота.ру]](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/author/litnevskaya/part5#42101)

Answer (score -1):

> «Если спп, то где тут сложность предложения, когда сказуемые относятся к одному подлежащему?» —
> так это и не СПП. Кто-то вам сказал, что сказуемые при одном и том же подлежащем не могут стоять в разном времени? Это был вздор, и вы напрасно в него поверили))

Comment: https://gufo.me/dict/ushakov/когда

Comment: oleedd, и? Это СПП, что ли? Вообще-то, конечно, всегда убеждает словарь, пишущий «ковычки»)))

Comment: Получается, что в то время было два варианта написания этого слова. Если считать простым, то и запятую не ставить. А раз уж мы ставим...

Comment: «А раз уж мы ставим...» — то что))

Comment: То считаем сложным.

Comment: Запятая означает «считаем сложным»?))

Comment: Да: и в какое конкретно время «было два варианта написания этого слова»? Может быть, один из вариантов уже пора отбросить, как морально устаревший?

Comment: Возможно, у учёных такая логика. Пора отбросить, видимо, там исходный вариант словаря.

Comment: «Возможно, у учёных такая логика» — такая, что перед «когда» запятая ставится всегда?

Comment: Нет. Если бы запятая в этом случае не ставилась, то точно бы считали простым. Могут считать сложным из-за того, что в таких случаях нет исключения. Вспомните цельные выражения — запятой нет, и сложным не считается.

Comment: «Вспомните цельные выражения — запятой нет, и сложным не считается» — ну да, и это тоже, цельные выражения... Извините мою бестолковость, но я действительно никак не пойму, что от чего зависит: запятая от сложности предложения или сложность от запятой. При любом ответе: а от чего зависит первое?

Comment: «Если бы запятая в этом случае не ставилась, то точно бы считали простым» — ? Моё ЧЯ (чувство языка) орёт, что запятая в топикстартовой фразе совершенно необходима, но не потому, что СПП, а просто потому, что конструкция «времена (время, пора и т. п.), когда...» требует запятой. Что, такая конструкция всегда даёт СПП?

Comment: Сложность от запятой. А запятая связана с традицией, а она — с наличием паузы. По правилам грамматики да, всегда даёт, так давно решили лингвисты, а потом ничего не менялось (в грамматике вроде бы никогда ничего не меняется). С другими подчинительными союзами то же.